# is there in C# a method for List<T> like resize in c++ for vector<T>

Tags: c#, c++, list, vector

When I use `resize(int newsize)` in C++ for `vector<T>`, it means that the `size` of this `vector` are set to `newsize` and the indexes run in range `[0..newsize)`. How to do the same in C# for `List<T>`?
Changing the `List<T>` property `Capacity` only changes the `Capacity` but leaves the `Count` the same, and furthermore the indexes still are in range `[0..Count)`. Help me out, please.

P.S. Imagine I have a `vector<T> tmp` with a `tmp.size() == 5` I cannot refer to `tmp[9]`, but when I then use `tmp.resize(10)` I may refer to `tmp[9]`. In C# if I have `List<T> tmp` with `tmp.Count == 5` I cannot refer to `tmp[9]` (`IndexOutOfRangeException`), but even when I set `tmp.Capacity=10` I will not be able to refer to `tmp[9]` coz of `tmp.Count` is still 5. I want to find some analogy of resize in C#.

Comment: just curious, why u wanna do that?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis `resize` increases size, `reserve` increases capacity.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need this?

Comment: "*it means that the `capacity` and `size` of this vector are set to `newsize`*" No it doesn't; only the *`size`* will be set. The `capacity` may *or may not* be set to that.

Comment: If you want to change the size (`Count`) of a .NET `List`, just add to or remove elements from it.

Comment: @millimoose that's what `std::vector<T>::resize()` does as a handy method for adding or removing the amount required. It's nothing you couldn't do yourself, but it is a convenience that that C++ class has, that the equivalent C# class does not.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, but you can use extension methods to add your own. The following has the same behaviour as `std::vector<T>::resize()`, including the same time-complexity. The only difference is that in C++ we can define a default with `void resize ( size_type sz, T c = T() )` and the way templates work means that that's fine if we call it without the default for a `T` that has no accessible parameterless constructor. In C# we can't do that, so instead we have to create one method with no constraint that matches the non-default-used case, and another with a `where new()` constraint that calls into it.

```
public static class ListExtra
{
    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int sz, T c)
    {
        int cur = list.Count;
        if(sz < cur)
            list.RemoveRange(sz, cur - sz);
        else if(sz > cur)
        {
            if(sz > list.Capacity)//this bit is purely an optimisation, to avoid multiple automatic capacity changes.
              list.Capacity = sz;
            list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(c, sz - cur));
        }
    }
    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int sz) where T : new()
    {
        Resize(list, sz, new T());
    }
}
```

Now the likes of `myList.Resize(23)` or `myList.Resize(23, myDefaultValue)` will match what one expects from C++'s vector. I'd note though that sometimes where with C++ you'd have a vector of pointers, in C# you'd have a list of some reference-type. Hence in cases where the C++ `T()` produces a null pointer (because it's a pointer), here we're expecting it to call a parameterless constructor. For that reason you might find it closer to the behaviour you're used to to replace the second method with:

```
  public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int sz)
  {
      Resize(list, sz, default(T));
  }
```

This has the same effect with value types (call parameterless constructor), but with reference-types, it'll fill with nulls. In which case, we can just rewrite the entire class to:

```
public static class ListExtra
{
    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int sz, T c = default(T))
    {
        int cur = list.Count;
        if(sz < cur)
            list.RemoveRange(sz, cur - sz);
        else if(sz > cur)
            list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(c, sz - cur));
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't so much about differences between `std::vector<T>` and `List<T>` as about the differences in how pointers are used in C++ and C#.

Comment: do we really need list.Capacity = sz; Do not AddRange knows the size of adding Collection?

Comment: @fantastory no, it's not needed, as indicated by the comment.

Comment: The question is, do we need it for optimization. Yes we need because AddRange does not know size of enumeration before enumerating it.

Comment: Mind you the `where T : new()` version will cause any added elements to reference the same object... Probably better to loop the additions with `while (list.Count < list.Capacity) { list.Add(new T()); }` instead, since that's most likely the desired fuctionality..

Comment: @Conduit or perhaps better would be to have a form that takes a factory that can be called, with `() -> new T()` being given as a default.

Comment: @JonHanna ooh, hadn't thought of that - not a bad plan on account of being so flexible for constructors that might need arguments.

Comment: ...further generic arguments required, though, if I'm not mistaken? More familiar with C++ templates than C# generics... miss my `Args...` :(

Comment: Nice. Though for me I would probably use null as the default if it's a reference type.

Answer (score 23):

Just to make [Jon Hanna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232162/968095) more readable:

```
public static class ListExtras
{
    //    list: List<T> to resize
    //    size: desired new size
    // element: default value to insert

    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int size, T element = default(T))
    {
        int count = list.Count;

        if (size < count)
        {
            list.RemoveRange(size, count - size);
        }
        else if (size > count)
        {
            if (size > list.Capacity)   // Optimization
                list.Capacity = size;

            list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(element, size - count));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (size > list.Capacity) list.Capacity = size;` This optimization is **very** bad. Consider example: for(int i = 0; i< 100000; i++) lst.Resize(i);

Answer (score 1):

sorry. is this what u need? 
[List.TrimExcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.

```
private void listResize<T>(List<T> list, int size)
{
   if (size > list.Count)
      while (size - list.Count > 0)
         list.Add(default<T>);    
   else if (size < list.Count)
      while (list.Count - size > 0)
         list.RemoveAt(list.Count-1);
}
```

When the `size` and `list.Count` are the same, there is no need to resize the list.

The `default(T)` parameter is used instead of `null`,`""`,`0` or other nullable types, to fill an empty item in the list, because we don't know what type `<T>` is (reference, value, struct etc.).

> P.S. I used `for` loops instead of `while` loops and i ran into a
>   problem. Not always the size of the list was that i was asking for. It
>   was smaller. Any thoughts why?
>
> Check it:
>
> ```
> private void listResize<T>(List<T> list, int size)
> {
>    if (size > list.Count)
>       for (int i = 0; i <= size - list.Count; i++)
>          list.Add(default(T));
>    else if (size < list.Count)
>       for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count - size; i++)
>          list.RemoveAt(list.Count-1);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `List<T>.Capacity` is like using `std::vector<T>.reserve(..)`. Maybe `List<T>.AddRange(..)` fit your needs.

Comment: Thnx, but I then will need to create the new range of items I want to add to the end of my current list :( I want to change only some integer value which represents the size of List<T>

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 8 instead of custom extension methods you can use [`CollectionsMarshal.SetCount<T>(List<T>, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.setcount?view=net-8.0) which supports both increasing and decreasing initialized list size and should be a bit more performant:

```cs
var ints = new List<int>();
CollectionsMarshal.SetCount(ints, 20);
Console.WriteLine(ints.Count); // prints 20
CollectionsMarshal.SetCount(ints, 10);
Console.WriteLine(ints.Count); // prints 10
```

Answer (score -2):

Haven't you read at MSDN:-

> A list is a **resizable collection of items**. Lists can be constructed
>   multiple ways, but the most useful class is List. This allows you
>   to strongly type your list, includes all of the essential
>   functionality for dealing with collections, and can be easily
>   searched.

Further:-

> *Capacity*  is the number of elements that the List can store before
>   resizing is required, while Count is the number of elements that are
>   actually in the List.
>
> **Capacity  is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds
>   Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by
>   automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old
>   elements and adding the new elements**.

Comment: @novaco:- yes updated, see why you dont need to resize it... :)

Comment: Because while `std::vector<T>::resize` doesn't do anything you can't do by other means, if you're used to it, you'll certain miss it.

Answer (score -7):

A list doesn't have a finite size.

Is there a reason why the size matters to you?

Perhaps an array or a dictionary is closer to your requirements